# Cross-platform Xamarin Changing Icon

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm new to Xamarin, I'm doing Visual Studio with Xamarin Cross-platform development and I want to change the icon on my **app.droid**, well I've already read a lot, everything I've read is saying to replace every drawable folder under resources, but I guess that will be too much effort and even following the pixel format depending on the drawable folder (e.g. drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, etc) so my question is, is/are there any way(s) I can replace the icon of the app for different folders with lesser effort.  Example in Ionic/Cordova I just have to do an `ionic resources --icon` and replace the image inside the folder resources, and will automatically create the icon to the different drawable folders.

Comment: I use custom build targets to convert vector/svg to the various icon sizes, but there are lots of generators available. This is an online/javascript version that creates a zip of all the launcher sizes (mipmap-xxxx) from an image that you can just extract into your `Resources` dir: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html

Comment: WOW! this is great! thanks sir @SushiHangover